# Use of Unresolved Identifier 'self' in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices
import AVFoundation
import AWSAuthCore

class ViewController: UIViewController, SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate, SPTAudioStreamingDelegate  {
    // Variables
    var auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()!
    var session:SPTSession!

    // Initialzed in either updateAfterFirstLogin: (if first time login) or in viewDidLoad (when there is a check for a session object in User Defaults
    var player: SPTAudioStreamingController?
    var loginUrl: URL?

    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var loginSpotify: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setup()
    }

    func setup () {
        // insert redirect your url and client ID below
        let redirectURL = "splitter-app://callback" // put your redirect URL here
        let clientID = "client id goes here" // put your client ID here
        auth.redirectURL     = URL(string: redirectURL)
        auth.clientID        = "client id goes here"
        auth.requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope, SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPrivateScope]
        loginUrl = auth.spotifyWebAuthenticationURL()
        print("test")
    }

    func initializePlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
        if self.player == nil {
            self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
            self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
            self.player!.delegate = self
            try! player!.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
            self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
        }

        func updateAfterFirstLogin ()  {
            loginSpotify.isHidden = true
            let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
            if let sessionObj:AnyObject = userDefaults.object(forKey: "SpotifySession") as AnyObject? {
                let sessionDataObj = sessionObj as! Data
                let firstTimeSession = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: sessionDataObj) as! SPTSession
                self.session = firstTimeSession
                initializePlayer(authSession: session)
            }
        }

        func initializaPlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
            if self.player == nil {
                self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
                self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
                self.player!.delegate = self
                try! player?.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
                self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
            }
        }
    }
}

func audioStreamingDidLogin(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!) {
    // after a user authenticates a session, the SPTAudioStreamingController is then initialized and this method called
    print("logged in")
    self.player?.playSpotifyURI("spotify:track:58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp", startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 0, callback: { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("playing!")
        }
    })
}
```

The error is on line 91. Xcode says:

> "Use of unresolved identifier 'self'"

however I have used that same variable in multiple different places in the code and it is declared at the top of the class. Why is it giving me an error on this specific line? I have tried making it a lazy variable as other people online have suggested, however Xcode tells me lazy variables need to be initialized and I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: `audioStreamingDidLogin` is not within the `class`.

Comment: you forget to close initializePlayer method

Comment: Basically your curly braces don't balance. They have _meaning_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting of the code makes it challenging to see what's going on, but it looks like the function audioStreamingDidLogin(:SPTAudioStreamingController!) is not a class function. Maybe global, because it's declared outside the class where self is available.

You may be able to:

- move it into the class
- pass some instance of ViewController into the method as a parameter

Moving it into the class makes most sense to me.

Edit: Fix code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegate, SPTAudioStreamingDelegate  {
    // Variables
    var auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()!
    var session:SPTSession!

    // Initialzed in either updateAfterFirstLogin: (if first time login) or in viewDidLoad (when there is a check for a session object in User Defaults
    var player: SPTAudioStreamingController?
    var loginUrl: URL?

    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var loginSpotify: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setup()
    }

    func setup () {
        // insert redirect your url and client ID below
        let redirectURL = "splitter-app://callback" // put your redirect URL here
        let clientID = "client id goes here" // put your client ID here
        auth.redirectURL     = URL(string: redirectURL)
        auth.clientID        = "client id goes here"
        auth.requestedScopes = [SPTAuthStreamingScope, SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPublicScope, SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPrivateScope]
        loginUrl = auth.spotifyWebAuthenticationURL()
        print("test")
    }

    func initializePlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
        if self.player == nil {
            self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
            self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
            self.player!.delegate = self
            try! player!.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
            self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
        }
    }

    func updateAfterFirstLogin ()  {
        loginSpotify.isHidden = true
        let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let sessionObj:AnyObject = userDefaults.object(forKey: "SpotifySession") as AnyObject? {
            let sessionDataObj = sessionObj as! Data
            let firstTimeSession = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: sessionDataObj) as! SPTSession
            self.session = firstTimeSession
            initializePlayer(authSession: session)
        }
    }

    func initializaPlayer(authSession:SPTSession){
        if self.player == nil {
            self.player = SPTAudioStreamingController.sharedInstance()
            self.player!.playbackDelegate = self
            self.player!.delegate = self
            try! player?.start(withClientId: auth.clientID)
            self.player!.login(withAccessToken: authSession.accessToken)
        }
    }

    func audioStreamingDidLogin(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!) {
        // after a user authenticates a session, the SPTAudioStreamingController is then initialized and this method called
        print("logged in")
        self.player?.playSpotifyURI("spotify:track:58s6EuEYJdlb0kO7awm3Vp", startingWith: 0, startingWithPosition: 0, callback: { (error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("playing!")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: It already is in the class. Sorry if the formatting is confusing, I just pasted it from Xcode. But everything is in the class I believe.

Comment: @JeffreyMatthew Hi. Your reformatted code makes it look even more like it's outside the closing bracket of the class.

Comment: @JeffreyMatthew What do you actually mean by **In the class**? Are you referring to **same file** instead of **class scope**? This func needs to be in the scope of the class, meaning the code should go inside the `{ ... }` of the class that is the _scope of the class_.

Comment: @JeffreyMatthew The updateAfterFirstLogin is also inside another class. The scope of the class is defined by it's opening and closing brace, not just the file itself.

Comment: @ScottMcKenzie You mean `updateAfterFirstLogin` is also inside another *function*.